# how to install mariadb on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: apt, 15.04

hi when i try to install mariadb when i tried to update using sudo apt-get update im getting this error 
N: Ignoring file 'apt-build' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
It pops up this message everytime I want to install something using apt-get install. What tot do? I am working on Ubuntu15.04. THX for help

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a file into that directory?  Take a look at that file by opening a terminal and entering "less /etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt-build" and see if it contains lines that appear in this format:

```
deb http://example.com/linux/deb/ stable main
```

if so, do you remember adding that yourself?  I would reccomend removing the file but if it does have entries like the example above, and you know why the file is there, then rename the file to have a .list extension, and then run "sudo apt-get update" in a terminal, and assuming that the addresses in that file are valid, that should clear up your issues.